# масм32 не могу сравнивать с -2 < 0 плиз помагите

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none;
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\debug.inc
includelib\masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib\masm32\lib\debug.lib
.data
i dw -2             ;i*k+k/2,    i>=2
k dw 4             ;2*i*i+k,     i<0
eki dw 2           ;3*i*i*i-k,   0<=i<=2
.code
begin:
xor ax,ax
xor bx,bx

.IF (i >= 2) ;i*k+k/2
mov ax,i
mul k
mov bx,ax
mov ax,0
mov ax,k
div eki
add ax,bx


.ElSEIF (i < 0) ;2*i*i+k вот здесь сравниваеться -2<0    
mov ax,0
mov ax,2
mul i
mul i
add ax,k

.ELSEIF (i >= 0 && i <= 2) ;3*i*i*i-k
mov ax,0
mov ax,3
mul i
mul i
mul i
sub ax,k
.ENDIF
PrintDec ax
end begin
```

Comment: Навсикидку - возможно происходит беззнаковое сравнение вместо знакового. Я бы попробвал переделать через cmp и jg / jng/ jl / jnl потому что не очевидно, какой код генерится этими макросами, может там беззнаковое сравнение используется (ja / jna / jb / jnb). Хотя можно попробовать сгенерировать листинг (или в дизассемблере открыть), и посмотреть, какой именно код получился.

Comment: А, кстати, для знаковых чисел нужно использовать idiv и imul вместо div и mul